# Ocaml : Passing constructor type between modules

Tags: types, module, ocaml, abstract

I have this module type :

```
module type MOD =    
  sig   
    type operand
    type op
    val print : op -> string
  end;;
```

An implementation of MOD is :

```
module M1:MOD =
  struct
    type operand = Mem of int | Reg of int | Const of int
    type op = Add of operand * operand| Sub of operand * operand
    let print op = match op with
      | Add _ -> "Add"
      | Sub _ -> "Sub"
  end;;
```

I want to create a parametrized module witch take `op` type from the first module
and implement function on variables of that type. like this:

```
module  ARCHI = functor (M : MOD) ->
  struct
    type op = M.op

    let execute o = match o with
      | Add (x,y) -> x + y
      | Sub (x,y) -> x - y
  end;;
```

I get error `: Unbound constructor Add`. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 8):

You have declared type `op` to be abstract in MOD, and then you have defined your functor to take module M of type MOD. Thus, you correctly cannot have access to the implementation of op. Otherwise, your functor doesn't do what it claims to which is take *any* module of type MOD, not just the specific M1 you've defined.

You can expose the implementation of op in MOD by writing out the full definition of the type in the signature. However, it's not clear that you actually need a functor at all here.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a declaration of `Add` anywhere in `ARCHI`. The `Add` constructor of `M` would have to be written `M.Add`. Furthermore, as already [noted by Ashish Agarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728830/ocaml-passing-constructor-type-between-modules/8729945#8729945), the `ARCHI` module can take an argument that doesn't have an `Add` constructor, since the signature `MOD` does not mention any constructor called `Add`.

If you want to use `Add` in `M`, you must declare it in when you declare `M`, i.e. in the argument to the constructor. One way to do that is to fully specify the type `op` in the signature `MOD`:

```
module type MOD = sig 
    type operand
    type op = Add of operand * operand| Sub of operand * operand
    val print : op -> string
  end;;
```

If you're using the signature `MOD` for other purposes where the `op` type must remain abstract, there is a notation for adding type equalities to a signature. With the original definition of `MOD`, you can write

```
module type MOD_like_M1 =
  MOD with type op = Add of operand * operand| Sub of operand * operand
module ARCHI = functor (M : MOD_like_M1) -> …
```

or

```
module type MOD_like_M1 = MOD with type op = M1.op
module ARCHI = functor (M : MOD_like_M1) -> …
```

or

```
module type MOD_like_M1 =
  MOD with type op = Add of operand * operand| Sub of operand * operand
module ARCHI = functor (M : MOD with type op = M1.op) -> …
```

In any case, in the definition of `ARCHI`, you need to `open M` or to write `M.Add`.